# How does string literals work in c (especially wide character strings - L"some string")?

Tags: c, string, unicode, string-literals, wchar-t

In my code, I have a line that follows:

```
wchar_t wstr[] = L"ABC কখগ ";
```

My question is - are those characters stored as UTF-16 encoded characters or as
decoded unicode codepoints?

Comment: Encoding of characters is left for the "implementation", i.e. the compiler. And a compiler can choose different encodings on different operating systems.

Comment: And the actual underlying type of `wchar_t` is *also* left for the implementation. The MSVC compiler typically uses two bytes, while GCC (at least on Linux) commonly uses four bytes.

Comment: Anyways, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal for more information.